# where are the threads waken up from Object.notifyAll and failing to get the lock?

Tags: java, synchronized

Below is how monitor works:
[monitor](https://user-gold-cdn.xitu.io/2018/3/29/16270c8c43663a52?imageView2/0/w/1280/h/960/format/webp/ignore-error/1)

- Threads in wait set are waken up when Object.notifyAll() is called.
- Only one of them get the lock, while the others are blocked again.
- So where do the blocked threads go?Will they go back to wait set or go to entry set?Or this is managed by the os, because monitor depends on the os MutexLock?

Comment: They go back into the wait set, of course. I don't know what you mean by 'entry set'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monitor is a fundamental conception that you should understand. It is better to read about it somewhere.

In short, I could say that there are some major principles:

1. If a thread go into the synchronized block - the monitor of synchronized object is blocked and all other threads couldn't
   execute the synchronized block (they are in the Entry Set).
2. If you call wait() method on synchronized object, then the thread go to Wait Set
3. If you call notify()/notifyAll() method on synchronized object, it means that one/all thread(s) go to Entry Set from Wait Set.

The answer to your question is - when you call notifyAll() method, all threads from Wait Set go to Entry Set.

Comment: @Zili Jin if my answer help you, please, accept it. Otherwise ask me to clarify.

Comment: Thanks. But the picture in the question above shows that threads in the "wait set" acquire the lock directly, without going to "entry set".

Comment: Besides, how is a thread in the "entry set" chosen to acquire the lock? Is it chosen arbitrarily？

Comment: @Zili Jin thread from Entry or Wait Set is chosen randomly. But there is a `java.util.concurrent` package that contains some locks with fairness (e.g.: `ReentrantLock`). It is a bit tricky to talk about Entry Set. Thread from Wait Set that is waken up by calling `notify()` begin working from exactly the line where wait() was called and probably the picture shows it. Let's consider an example - the thread from Entry Set go to synchronized block, then wait() is called and the thread go to Wait Set, then notify() is called and thread go to execute the code from place where wait was called().